# Google Picasa API XML deserialization - follow up

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, picasa

Im trying to write a class to deserialize the picasa album feed. It has been pretty good so far, got some help to get started ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263822/google-picasa-api-xml-deserialization)) and I'm almost there. I have a problem with two fields right now.

The gphoto:bytesUsed and gphoto:numphotosremaining want deserialize. I can't find anything wrong with it. Thankfull for any suggestions.

Url to feed: https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/{username}

Class code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    [XmlType("feed", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
    [XmlRoot("feed", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
    public class picasa
    {
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string title { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string icon { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("link")]
    public FeedLink[] links { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("generator")]
    public FeedGenerator generator { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("author")]
    public FeedAuthor author { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/")]
    public int totalResults { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("entry")]
    public FeedEntry[] entries { get; set; }

    [XmlType("entry", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
    public partial class FeedEntry
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public string id { get; set; }

        [XmlElement]
        public FeedCategory category { get; set; }

        [XmlElement]
        public string title { get; set; }

        [XmlElement]
        public string summary { get; set; }

        [XmlElement]
        public string rights { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("link")]
        public FeedLink[] links { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("author")]
        public FeedAuthor author { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "id", Namespace = "http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007")]
        public string gid { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "name", Namespace = "http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007")]
        public string gname { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "location", Namespace = "http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007")]
        public string glocation { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "access", Namespace = "http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007")]
        public string gaccess { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "timestamp", Namespace = "http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007")]
        public string gtimestamp { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "numphotos", Namespace = "http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007")]
        public int gnumphotos { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "numphotosremaining", Namespace = "http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007")]
        public int gnumphotosremaining { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "bytesUsed", Namespace = "http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007")]
        public int gbytesUsed { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "user", Namespace = "http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007")]
        public string guser { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "nickname", Namespace = "http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007")]
        public string gnickname { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "commentingEnabled", Namespace = "http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007")]
        public string gcommentingEnabled { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "commentCount", Namespace = "http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007")]
        public int gcommentCount { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "group", Namespace = "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/")]
        public MediaGroup mgroup { get; set; }


    }

    #region XML types
    [XmlType("author", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
    public partial class FeedAuthor
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "name", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "uri", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
        public string uri { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlType("category", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
    public partial class FeedCategory
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "scheme", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
        public string scheme { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "term", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
        public string term { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlType("link", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
    public partial class FeedLink
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "rel", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
        public string rel { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
        public string type { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "href", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlType("generator", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
    public partial class FeedGenerator
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "version", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
        public string version { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "uri", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
        public string uri { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlType("group", Namespace = "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/")]
    public partial class MediaGroup
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "content", Namespace = "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/")]
        public MediaContent mgcontent { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "credit", Namespace = "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/")]
        public string mgcredit { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "description", Namespace = "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/")]
        public MediaDescription mgdescription { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlType("content", Namespace = "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/")]
    public partial class MediaContent
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "url", Namespace = "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/")]
        public string url { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type", Namespace = "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/")]
        public string type { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "medium", Namespace = "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/")]
        public string medium { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlType("description", Namespace = "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/")]
    public partial class MediaDescription
    {
        [XmlAttribute("type", Namespace="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/")]
        public string type {get;set;}

        [XmlText]
        public string description { get; set; }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution could be dramatically simplified making use of the [.NET library for the Google Data API](http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/downloads/detail?name=Google_Data_API_Setup_1.9.0.0.msi&can=2&q=). Plus here is a tutorial that you might find interesting: [Creating your first Picasa Web C# Application](http://www.brighthub.com/hubfolio/matthew-casperson/articles/52189.aspx).

Comment: I have looked at that but the client library for .Net only supports version 1 of the API and version 2.